# Using Table per Hierarchy can you set the discriminator for the base class?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using EF 4.3 and TPH.

My base class is `User` and I also have a class `Customer` which derives from `User` with a few additional fields.

In my database I have a column called `UserType` which I use as the discriminator. I want Customer to = 'C' and User to = 'U'

I want "regular" users of the app to be of type `User` and Customers to be of type `Customer`. They both login the same way and their primary difference besides a few fields is permissions so its convenient for me to model it this way.

I can get `Customer` working fine by setting up my context like this:

```
mb.Entity<User>().Map<Customer>(m=>m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("C"));
```

My question is if I wish to create a regular `User` entity, how can I tell EF to use "U" as the discriminator.

I'm trying to avoid deriving another class from User, since User already fits my needs. But maybe that's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can set discriminator value for your base type:

```
mb.Entity<User>().Map(m => m.Requires("UserType").HasValue("U"));
```

Comment: When I try that the error I get is "Map was called more than once for type 'User' and at least one of the calls didn't specify the target table name."